# Installation did not complete successfully. Platform-26_r02.zip

Tags: android, sdk

I have tried all the solutions stated in previous posts. Have already changed the path but nothing is happening. Installation fails to succeed at this point. This is the latest version of android studio. I cannot find find separate .exe file for SDK Manager to install it manually. Appreciate the help.

This is what i am getting

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually download packages which are failing in Android Studio due to network connectivity issues :

For this package goto this link: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-26_r02.zip

It was already in the screenshot you provided.

Now create a folder in `SDK_DIRECTORY\platforms` & name it `android-SDK_INT`. `SDK_INT` is the version code, in your case, it's *26* (from 26_r02)

So the folder name in this case will be **android-26** (`SDK\platforms\android-26`)

Extract the downloaded zip, you'll see a folder named **android-8.0.0**, *copy* all contents from it and *paste* to the folder we created before.

It will look like this below (when you're done)

[image: It will look like this]

Comment: I'm here for that, so no thanks. For any help free feel to ask again

Comment: For 8.0(oreo) and 7.1.1, how many platforms do we have ? I mean what are the android-INT platforms do we need ?

Comment: android-24 = 7.0 **||** android-25 = 7.1 **||** android-26 = 8.0 **||** android-27 = 8.1